# How to login phone.ipkall.com with python requests library?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am try to learn python, but I have no knowledge about HTTP, I read some posts here about how to use requests to login web site. But it doesn't work. My simple code is here (not real number and password):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

login_data = {'txtDID': '111111111',
              'txtPswd': 'mypassword'}

with requests.Session() as c:
    c.post('http://phone.ipkall.com/login.asp', data=login_data)
    r = c.get('http://phone.ipkall.com/update.asp')
    print(r.text)

print("Done")
```

But I can't get my personal information which should be showed after login. Can anyone give me some hint? Or point me a direction? I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: look at what the post-request returns? Btw. the correct url is `http://phone.ipkall.com/process.asp?action=verify`.

Comment: Also noteworthy, if you care about security, is that the login pages are not SSL protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers don't like bots (scripts) for security reason. So your script have to behave like human using real browser. First use `get()` to get session cookies, set `user-agent` in `headers` to real one. Use `http://httpbin.org/headers` to see what `user-agent` is send by your browser.

Always check results `r.status_code` and `r.url`

So you can start with this:
(I don't have acount on this server so I can't test it)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests

s = requests.Session()

s.headers.update({
    'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0",    
})

# --------
# to get cookies, session ID, etc.

r = s.get('http://phone.ipkall.com/login.asp')

print( r.status_code, r.url )

# --------

login_data = {
    'txtDID': '111111111',
    'txtPswd': 'mypassword',
    'submit1': 'Submit'
}

r = s.post('http://phone.ipkall.com/process.asp?action=verify', data=login_data)

print( r.status_code, r.url )

# --------
```

BTW: If page use `JavaScript` you have problem because `requests` can't run `javascript` on page.